# UserControl.Resources / Obtain Reference to ViewModel

Tags: xml, silverlight, mvvm

I instanciate my VM like this:

```
DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocatorService}, Path=FlowDateRatchetViewModel}"
```

Which is fine, but when I'm binding to my commands, I usually do this:

```
Command="{Binding ElementName=ucFlowDateRatchets, Path=DataContext.AddFlowDateRatchetCommand}"
```

Which is what I have to do when I'm in a template as the DataContext is within the ViewModel, and this allows me to start from the top.

Is there a way to do something like:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <VM:FlowDateRatchet x:key="FlowDateRatchetViewModel" Constructor?????={Binding....
</UserControl.Resources>
```

so that the command would be:

```
Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource FlowDateRatchetViewModel}, Path=AddFlowDateRatchetCommand}"
```

I always seem to have trouble ensuring that I'm starting at the right context when I specify my databinding, and this syntax would ensure the root was stable.  IMHO

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

[Dan Wahlin](https://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin) Had a very simliar issue, and wanted to simplify the binding to the DataContext of parent control and came up with this beauty: [DataContextProxy](https://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-a-silverlight-datacontext-proxy-to-simplify-data-binding-in-nested-controls).  While I was attempting to instanciate a class and gain referenc to it (just like you gain reference to a class via the DataContext property), Dan took another route and allows the DataContext to create and gain reference to the instanciated class.  As he describes in his article, he has created a class that references the DataContext property of the parent object, and exposes that reference in a User.Resources reference (hence the Proxy suffix!).  Bindings can then gain a reference by simply using the StaticReference binding attribute.

I was accomplishing the same thing by either 1) naming the UserControl, and using the ElementName attribute (disadvantage is that you have named the UC, and mulitple uses of the same UC would result in duplicate names on a page), or 2) in SL5 using the RelativeSource, and via AncestorType, pointing it to the UserControl.  Both of which are long winded and require the path to be Path="DataContext." which I hated.

Still experimenting, but I think this will do the trick nicely, and ensure clarity in the bindings.

I made one small change, and sprinkled a little RX love to subscribe to an event via a weak reference:

```
Observable.FromEvent<RoutedEventArgs>(this,"Loaded")
          .Subscribe(pEvent => DataContextProxy_Loaded(pEvent.Sender, pEvent.EventArgs));
```

rather than

```
this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(DataContextProxy_Loaded);
```